# Check if jQuery .find() is undefined when used inside of .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm using the following script to run through a menu of items and measure the left offset. My problem here is not every element will contain the 'ul' I'm looking for. I have tried looking through the ul and hitting the parent but that never triggered correctly. I then tried measuring .length and no go. I've also tried comparing against 'undefined'. I'm totally stumped odds are I'm doing something stupid and I just can't see passed the obvious.

```
$('#nav ul.nav-tier-2 li').each(function(){
        var leftQ = $(this).find('ul').offset().left;
  //Extra code below
}
```

Example of of HMTL

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul class="nav-tier-1">
   <li>
     <a>Link Text</a>
     <ul class="nav-tier-2">
       <li>
         <a></a>
         <ul class="nav-tier-3">
           <li><a> Last link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: `var $ul = $(this).find('ul'); if ($ul.length===1) { /* found */ }`

Comment: `if($(this).find('ul').length > 0){ ...`

Comment: Don't you read the description of the question ? He said he tried already to measure length.

Comment: you dont need to each like that to check with length, better of with `$('#nav ul.nav-tier-2 li').find('ul').each(`

Comment: @Kosmo - Yes, but didn't show the relevant code for that, so may have done so incorrectly. Measuring `.length` is the normal way to see if a jQuery object contains any elements (i.e., if a selector matched anything), so...

Comment: What's this mean? "I then tried measuring .length and no go." $(this).find('ul').length gives you > 0 even when there's no ul or throws error or?

Comment: Also what does console.log($(this).find('ul')) tell you on these cases?

Comment: If you have nested ULs, as your code implies, you need to make the outer selector more specific: `$('#nav ul.nav-tier-2 > li')` or you will include the grandchild `LI`s in the top search.

Comment: Can you also please define the criteria for `"the 'ul' I'm looking for"`?

Comment: it will throw exception undefined() if it doesn't find the 'ul' . I think you first find it and then check it's length . It it exists then apply offset .

Comment: @nnnnnn Just what I needed to resolve against. The vagueness of the selectors is what I needed in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of the HTML structure this is guesswork, but it will cut out the extra search and avoid descendant `UL`s that do not exist:

Note: the first selector is more specific (using the `>` child selector) to avoid including grandchild LIs. You may need to adjust this is you have many levels deep.

```
$('#nav ul.nav-tier-2 > li ul').each(function(){
        var leftQ = $(this).offset().left;
  //Extra code below
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7xkdeq16/

Comment: I've tried that but late when I try and target the parent 'li' it does seem to find it

Comment: @TheHamstring: I added the missing brackets and made a JSFiddle for you :) The console shows a `leftQ` value of `88` when run in Chrome.